# Criar um site com programação JAVA?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como poderia começar para criar um simples site através de programação JAVA.
Se alguém puder ajudar ou indicar algum tutorial, agradeço muito!
Obrigado

Comment: Recomendo a leitura dessa apostila: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/ ela também está disponível para download no site deles nesta url: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostilas/ Ela vai direto ao ponto além de ser de fácil entendimento. Recomendo!

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Você pode dar uma lida nesse material [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), ele pode te dar uma luz. Também lhe aconselho a fazer um [tour] para conhecer um pouco melhor o modelo do site.

Answer (score 4):

Existem **muitas** alternativas para fazer isso. Mas no geral, a idéia consiste em:

1. Página HTML tendo um formulário para que o usuário entre com as informações necessárias;
2. Uma vez com as informações, um servidor recebe essas informações e as consome (é aqui que o Java entra!) e retorna algo;
3. A página então reage à resposta do servidor, mostrando o que o cliente deseja.

Uma biblioteca em `java` que pode ajudar na sua intenção é a [`Apache HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) para envio de requisições e respostas por `HTTP`. Para o servidor, pode usar o [`Apache Tomcat`](http://tomcat.apache.org/) ou [`Apache Hadoop`](http://hadoop.apache.org/).

Estou dando uma resposta muito superficial com algumas recomendações pois a pergunta é **MUITO** ampla.

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ser sobre programação, e mesmo assim ser ampla demais, acho que sua resposta foi a mais genérica possível, sem citar `Frameworks` ou `Libs JS` +1

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio a questão é esta, se a pergunta não é sobre programação, ela não deveria ter sido respondida. No máximo comentamos nestes casos.

Comment: @Bigown mas a pergunta é sobre programação [eu acho] rs e na minha opinião muito boa por sinal! Muitos Programadores iniciantes achariam esse tipo de pergunta - respostas chamativas para a rede SOpt, porém, regras são regras....

Comment: Eu já penso o contrário, inclusive o resposta não vai ajudar ninguém começar de verdade. Já dei aulas e qualquer pessoa que leia isto vai ficar na mesma.

Comment: Yeap... pode ser, por ser superficial/genérica, pra quem está começando, pode parecer grego uma resposta bem elaborada, mas.. acho uma boa iniciativa